# response.getselectedbutton() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, google-apps-script

I am in school and trying to code a google apps script where I have a function bound to a doc with a custom menu that can create a new doc with the date, subject, and email it to the teacher of said subject. All was going according to plan until I decided to make it so that if I hit cancel instead of OK in one of the parameters I would get the default value of that parameter if I had not hit edit parameters so I could easily only change 1 or 2 things. The function works spotlessly, but now what's happening is I can't get the selected button for the alert that asks me if I want to edit parameters.

It just says

> "TypeError: response.getSelectedButton is not a function"

and won't let me run my function. Here's my code for the function.     This has worked fine for me in the past and I'm really not sure why it doesn't work now.

```
function Mathdoc() {   var ui = DocumentApp.getUi();   
       var d = new Date();
var s = (d.getDate()) + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
console.log(s);           
                  var response = ui.alert( 'Change parameters?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {  insert all my other code here}
```

Is there a glitch or something I'm missing? I'm new to JS and fairly new to web design altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method named `getSelectedButton()`. The `ui.alert()` just returns the button and nothing else

```
function Mathdoc() {   
  var ui=DocumentApp.getUi();   
  var d = new Date();
  var s = (d.getDate()) + '/' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '/' + d.getFullYear();
  console.log(s);           
  var response=ui.alert( 'Change parameters?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  if (response==ui.Button.YES) {  insert all my other code here}
```

[Look at example here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#alert(String,String,ButtonSet))

Comment: There is no method named `getSelectedButton()`.  The  ui.alert() just returns the button and nothing else

Comment: Ohhh. That's why it worked. I was using ui.prompt before, but I couldn't get rid of the text box so I used ui.alert. Ohhhhhhhhhhhhh.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, this function doesn't exist. Basically if you type a function on google and don't find anything, it means the function doesn't exist

EDIT : If you have an error message that says it doesn't exist, it means that the function really doesn't exist or that the library containing the function is missing. But in your case the function doesn't exist

Comment: Any advice on how to fix it?

Comment: You'll have to give me more infos for that. Is the program javascript only or did you use another language combined with javascript ? Like html/php for example

Comment: Nope, pure javascript. The function is running from a menu declared in a separate function and the file is bound to a google doc that I use as my control center. Need any more info?

Comment: The account is G suite, which might have something to do with it?

Comment: You can't differentiate 2 buttons with only Javascript. I'll need you to details every infos you got that you can share because it's littérally impossible only with what you told

Comment: Cooper posted something that'll probably help you. I didn't think about that option